# Configuring iptables for line network

Tags: iptables, virtualbox

I have a setup, consisting of 3 linux (CentOS) machines:

[image: Machines]

All machines the that are directly connected can ping each other.

I am trying to setup iptable rules to enable VM3 to ping VM1 and vice versa, and then connect VM1 to the internet and have all 3 machines able to access the internet.

I have enabled ip forwarding

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I have added two iptables rules in VM2

```
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

I have set the default in gateway /etc/sysconfig/network

```
VM3 - 172.16.61.1 
VM2 - 172.16.60.1
```

In VM3 I have run the command

```
> ip route get 172.16.60.1
172.16.60.1 via 172.16.61.1 dev eth1 src 172.16.61.2
```

However, this did not make it work.
Can you help me?

Comment: It's been a while since I last made a similar setup (except the VM3 was directly connected to the VM1), but I think you need to add a rule to the POSTROUTING table to Masquerade the IP address before you forward the packet. [This link](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html) might help you configure the network. Be aware you also will need to configure the DNS resolver on `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Indeed, I still had to set up IP masquerading. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow VM3 to access VM1 you will need to add a `MASQUERADE` rule in the nat table in the `POSTROUTING` chain. e.g

```
iptable -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

This will basically will put VM3 behind a NAT of VM3

Comment: Thank you! I solved it with iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE